# SVG path with equal height positions will not render

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I have an SVG path that I'm rendering with D3 and React - the path is positioned between two points with the vertical x y positions being equal - the path is a straight line.

The problem is is that when the vertical positions of the path are the same, the line will not render because the height of the element is 0px. The following path renders in the DOM but is not visible:

```html
<path d="M56,104L183,104" id="line" stroke="url(#linear-gradient)" stroke-width="2"></path>
```

But if I change the value in `104` in the path `d` attribute to `105`, then the line shows because it has 1px of height:

```html
<path d="M56,105L183,104" id="line" stroke="url(#linear-gradient)" stroke-width="2"></path>
```

The problem with this is that the line is not completely straight. If I remove the linear gradient, the line is visible. Here is my D3 code:

```js
const linearGradient = SVG.append('defs')
    .append('linearGradient')
    .attr('id', 'linear-gradient')
    .attr('gradientTransform', `${rotate}`)

linearGradient.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '50%')
    .attr('stop-color', color(1));

linearGradient.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '80%')
    .attr('stop-color', color(2));

SVG
    .selectAll(null)
    .data([el.y])
    .join('path')
    .attr('d', (value: Number[] | Iterable<Number>) => getLine(idx, arr)(value))
    .attr('id', 'line')

SVG
    .selectAll('#line')
    .attr('stroke', 'url(#linear-gradient)')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
```

How can I make this line draw using linear gradient with height positions of the two points the same?